# Create an object within the object's definition

Tags: c++, nested

I have a class that compares two objects, but I want it to be able to compare itself within itself (if that makes any sense). In other words, I want a Comparable to be a set of two Comparables, and allows them to be nested. For example, a comparable could be {A,B}, where both A and B are comparable, so A could be {C,D} and B could be {E,F} so the parent Comparable would be {{C,D},{E,F}}, allowing indefinite nesting. However, I know this is not possible in this example:

```
class Comparable
{
        Comparable A, B;
    public:
        Comparable(Comparable A, Comparable B)
        {this->A = A; this->B = B};
};
```

Would there be a way, preferably using classes, that would allow for that?

Comment: If you require infinite nesting you will need to upgrade your computer to at _least_ infinite memory.

Comment: @Captain Not infinite, but _indefinite_ nesting, or arbitrary nesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do that using pointers:

```
class Comparable
{
        Comparable *A, *B;
    public:
        Comparable(Comparable *A, Comparable *B)
        {this->A = A; this->B = B};
};
```

Keep in mind, that if you do this, you will have to worry about memory management, as in when and where these objects should be de-allocated. Smart pointers are the way to go.

Comment: Pointers are ugly, why not use references? And I say this for the constructor parameters

Comment: References as data members are a bad idea. And if you are storing pointers, you may as well be passing pointers in.

Comment: @Smac89 sorry, i see the ctor-params part now. your totally right.